# ¿Cómo sacar variable de onCreate?

Tags: java, android, variables

Dentro de `onCreate` tengo el siguiente fragmento de código:

```
final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);

// Check if regid already presents
if (regId.equals("")) {
    // Registration is not present, register now with GCM
    GCMRegistrar.register(this, SENDER_ID);
} else {
    // Device is already registered on GCM
    if (GCMRegistrar.isRegisteredOnServer(this)) {
        // Skips registration.
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bienvenido", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        String var=regId;
    } else {

        //...
```

Lo que trato de hacer es pasar el dato almacenado en la variable `regId`
 a un método que está afuera de `onCreate`, que es el siguiente:

```
public void getData() {
    class GetDataJSON extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{ 
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            DefaultHttpClient httpclient = 
                   new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());
            HttpPost httppost = 
                   new HttpPost("http://url.mx/selectAllJSON.php?id="+var);

            // Depends on your web service
            httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

            InputStream inputStream = null;
            String result = null; 

            // ...
```

Todo esto es en la misma clase, sin embargo, me indica error de sintaxis, ¿cómo podría hacer esto?

Comment: Recomiendo que uses Android Studio, a veces su analizador de código te informa como podrías solventar, lo que intentas ahcer

Comment: jejeje en realidad lo uso pero soy nob

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declara la variable `refId` fuera del metodo pero dentro de la clase. Esto hara que este disponible en todos los metodos de la instancia de la actividad.

```
class MiActividad extends Activity {
   String regId;

   void onCreate(...) {
       regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);
       // ...
   } 
}
```

El único semi-problema es que no podrás utilizar el modificador `final`. De todos modos no lo vas a necesitar si no modificas el valor en otro lado.

Luego lo utilizas donde lo necesites sin necesidad de hacer una declaracion:

```
//fijate que utiliza regId
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://url.mx/selectAllJSON.php?id=" + regId);
```

Answer (score 1):

Por otro lado usted puede hacer algunos cambios:
*si usted llama a getData desde onCreate puede usar algo asi* (añadido por comentario de rnrneverdies en el cual tiene razon que asumia que usted llamaba al metodo desde onCreate);

en el metodo onCreate;

```
    //..
    void onCreate(...) {
       final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);
       //se llama cuando sea nesesario, pasando la variable;
       getData(regId);
```

Y en el metodo `getData` al que pasamos la variable:

```
public void getData(final String regId) {

    class GetDataJSON extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {


        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
             DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());
             HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(
                                "http://tuescuelanoticias.x10.mx/selectAllJSON.php?id=" 
                                              + regId);

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: aqui asumes que el getData es invocado desde onCreate, cosa que no esta clara en la pregunta.

Comment: pues tienes razon al decir que no esta claro, bueno solo lo puse para brindar otra alternativa. Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias @rnrneverdies y Angel Angel,  probé exitosa mente la primera opción, también probare la segunda, mi pregunta es que hace el modificador final?

Comment: al establecer final indicas que el valor, una vez establecido, no puede modificarse.

Comment: me acabo de dar cuenta que respondi la pregunta sin leer el titulo, la respondi en vase a esto -> Lo que trato de hacer es pasar el dato almacenado en la variable regId a un método que esta afuera de onCreate, que es le siguiente. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

En efecto lo más lógico es declarar una variable global (en este caso la varible `var`), aunque otra opción sería generar el `regId` dentro del método `getData()` y de esa forma nos quitamos la variable global de encima. Pueden haber muchos enfoques, sería bueno esclarecer la pregunta para visualizar el objetivo final. Las respuestas anteriores son válidas, así que tiene opciones para escoger mister.
Saludos!